# MVC AJAX QUERY Callback not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to make a simple Jquery Ajax callback:

This is my Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnClient').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var txtClient1 = $('#txtClient').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/VistasController/AROrders',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: { txtClient: txtClient1},
                dataType: "json",
                success: successFunc,
                error: errorFunc
            });

            function successFunc(data) {
                alert("Sucess");
            }

            function errorFunc(result) {
                alert("Error" + result.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

This is my ASP.net c# code behind:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AROrders(string txtClient)
    {
            DataTable dtClients = clientData(txtClient);

            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtClientes.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dtClients.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }
            string ResultadoJSON = serializer.Serialize(rows);

            return this.Content(ResultadoJSON, "application/json");

    }
```

When I do a normal postback it works but with Jquery I get the error "Resource not found"

I have tried configuring the route in global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "", 
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            new { controller = "Vistas", action = "AROrders", txtClient = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        );
```

I have also tried changing the URL without success.

Is there anything wrong with the Jquery?

Comment: Always use the `Url.Action()` method so your urls are correctly generated - `url: '@Url.Action("AROrders", "Vistas")',`. And you also need to remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont specify the postfix `Controller` in your URL.
So instead of :

```
url: '/VistasController/AROrders',
```

chnage it to

```
url: '/Vistas/AROrders',
```

Answer (score 1):

The jquery will not stringify for you so do:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/VistasController/AROrders',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ txtClient: txtClient1}),
            dataType: "json",
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
        });
```